# Passing hidden invitation token field after being redirected from openid authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic

I'm trying to combine Ryan Bates' [Beta invitations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations) and [Open id](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic). The way it is setup is so that signup form has hidden field, invitation token that allows user to sign up. The invitation token is sent in url: /signup/:invitation_token

However when I use open_id, it redirects back to just /signup url without the invitation token. How do I have it so that the token is still being pass after the redirect. Here's the relevant code in open_id_authorization plugin

```
def open_id_redirect_url(open_id_request, return_to = nil, method = nil)
  open_id_request.return_to_args['_method'] = (method || request.method).to_s
  open_id_request.return_to_args['open_id_complete'] = '1'
  open_id_request.redirect_url(root_url, return_to || requested_url)
end

def requested_url
  relative_url_root = self.class.respond_to?(:relative_url_root) ?
    self.class.relative_url_root.to_s :
    request.relative_url_root
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{ActionController::Base.relative_url_root}#{request.path}"
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell the open_id plugin to return to `/signup/:invitation_token` instead of just `/signup`:

```
signup_url(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
```

Pass that to `open_id_redirect_url`. I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, though.